With Spring Boot and PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, how to resolve nested Properties?
I have a Spring Boot application.
I am including multiple dependencies, which have different PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configured.
One PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is reading Properties from a custom .properties file with a prefix like myResolver.
The file looks like this:
property.one=apple
property.two=${property.one}tree

I can inject both properties with $myResolver{property.one} correctly into my code.
However, when injecting $myResolver{property.two}, it gets injected as ${property.one}tree. ${property.one} is not resolved to apple.
How can I make Spring resolve nested properties inside properties files?

It seems that I need to write property.two=$myResolver{property.one}tree to resolve the nested property.
The prefix is important.
